# HTML & CSS: Float Attribute Issue

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an issue floating an `ul` next to some text.

Here is the image:

[image]

I'm thinking maybe I have to use the `relative` position attribute to display it the way I want it to? But, I know for a fact that the `float` property should be used, but it's not working for me. I've tried using another `div`(`logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper`) to create a wrapper for the text and `ul`, but the `float` property still isn't working....

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
     <div class="fixedWidth1">
        <div class="logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper">
        <p>The Official Website of<br />
        <span id="AndrewVuText">Andrew Vu</span></p>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">PROJECTS</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">COLLABORATE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div> <!-- Logo & Main Menu Wrapper DIV -->
   </div> <!-- Fixed Width 1 DIV -->
</div> <!-- Top Bar DIV -->
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#AndrewText  {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.fixedWidth1  {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper  {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.fixedWidth1 ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}

.fixedWidth1 ul li  {
    display: inline; /* LI are horizontal */
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid yellow;
}

.fixedWidth1 ul li a  {
    text-decoration: none; /* No UNDERLINE */
}

/* Normal, unvisited link */
.fixedWidth1 ul li a:link  {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Visited link */
.fixedWidth1 ul li a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Mouse over link */
.fixedWidth1 ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

/* Selected link */
.fixedWidth1 ul li a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Any help will do. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you set an explicit width on the UL? Without one, the float will not properly take effect.

Comment: i think you may be this http://jsfiddle.net/j8cq1neL/

Answer (score 0):

Hi now define your `p tag` `float left`  `.logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper` define this `overflow hidden` and as like this

```
.logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper>p{
    float:left;
}
.logoAndMainMenu-Wrapper{overflow:hidden;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8cq1neL/)**